# Unexpected token error when migrating to native classes for components

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I upgraded to Ember 3.11 and I want to start using native classes for my components. 
When I change a component class to something similar like:

```
    export default class MyClassName extends BaseComponent {

        myFieldName;

    }
```

I get a build error
"Parsing error: Unexpected token ;" because of the class field.

Ideas how to make sure ember-cli doesn't complain about the new syntax are more than welcome.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Following jelhan's suggestion below I updated my package.json file as in ember-cli/ember-new-output (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/master/package.json). This didn’t help. I also created a brand new ember project with a single component in it and I still have the same problem. 
This is the package.json file which gets generated when creating new ember project (ember-cli 3.11.0):

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Small description for my-project goes here",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
    "lint:js": "eslint .",
    "start": "ember serve",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ember/jquery": "^0.6.0",
    "@ember/optional-features": "^0.7.0",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~3.11.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^7.7.3",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^5.1.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-data": "~3.11.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-qunit": "^4.4.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^5.0.1",
    "ember-source": "~3.11.1",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.0.1",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "qunit-dom": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.* || >= 10.*"
  }
}
```

Seems like the new syntax works fine. The javascript code executes as expected. I guess the errors I see in the build output are eslint errors only. I need to figure out how to configure eslint to understand the new syntax.

Comment: You should check your babel configuration and the version of `ember-cli-babel` used. I would recommend to compare your dependencies and configuration fields against the output of `ember new my-project`. You don't have to run the command yourself. It's available as [`ember-cli/ember-new-output`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output) repo.

Comment: you're missing the value. What was the old syntax for this? You can do `myFieldName = "foobar";`. But a property without a value does not make sense.

Comment: In case the property is declared like myFieldName = "foobar"; then the error is "Parsing error: Unexpected token ="

Answer (score 0):

as @Lux pointed out in a comment, the value is missing.

This will fix your syntax error:

```
export default class MyClassName extends BaseComponent {
  myFieldName = undefined;
}
```

Also, be sure to have the latest version of ember-cli-babel installed to ensure that you have the latest bundled set of babel plugins -- earlier versions of ember-cli-babel did not support classes. The latest at the time of writing this is `7.10.0` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-babel

In classic syntax, this would be the equivalent of:

```
export default BaseComponent.extend({
  myFieldName: undefined,
});
```

If you're curious about more of the differences -- here is a bit more information on native javascript classes in Ember from the ember-decorators documentation: https://ember-decorators.github.io/ember-decorators/docs/native-class-basics

---

On a somewhat related note:

I know it's been common in Ember to define all the properties a component may receive at the top to declare its API, but now is actually a really good time to get in to TypeScript, so that you may add more semantic meaning to your classes.

Initializing a property as undefined is the same as not specifying it, so with TypeScript, you can attain better semantics with:

```
interface Args {
  myFieldName: string;
}

export default class MyClassName extends BaseComponent<Args> {

}
```

Assuming BaseComponent is a Glimmer Component, info here: https://octane-guides-preview.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/editions/#toc_tracked-properties
(EmberComponents don't accept Type Arguments, as far as I know)

Comment: As I explained in my reply to Lux's post the error comes regardless if the variable is initialized or not. In case the line is "myFieldName = undefined;" then the error is "error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =". The problem is that the native class syntax is not recognized. I submitted an issue with ember cli - https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/8780. Unfortunately, no comments there.

Comment: have you upgraded ember-cli-babel to the latest version?

Comment: maybe if eslint is what is giving you troubles, checkout the ember-octane blueprint https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-octane-blueprint/ via`ember new my-app -b @ember/octane-app-blueprint`. It configures eslint slightly differently than classic apps.